# How to get a collection of models using where and relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `Order` table with some relationships (`Status`, `User`) using their IDs to create it (`status_id`, `user_id`)

I need to get a collection of `Order` models using and  **Eloquent ORM** but I need to filter by their **status name** (which is in `Status` table only) and **user name** (which is in `User` table only)

When I use 'join' in my query builder. The relationships aren't hydrating, like in this case:

```
$emprestimo = DB::table('emprestimos')
            ->join('status', 'status_id', '=', 'status.id')
            ->where('status.nome', 'Solicitado')
            ->where('emprestimos.dono_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

How can I filter using joins and also hydrate my collection of models?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

see if that works

```
$emprestimo = DB::table('emprestimos')
            ->join('status', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('emprestimos.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
                                 ->where('status.nome', 'Solicitado')
                            })
            ->where('emprestimos.dono_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```